# Is there a way to take advantage of multiple CPU cores with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I've created a simple HTTP Server with python and asyncio. But, I have read that asyncio-based servers can only take advantage of one CPU core. I am trying to fix this with `multiprocessing` and it doesn't work. When I try to create a process, It gives me an error saying that it cannot create the process from _winapi. This is my code so far:

```
def serve_forever(self, host, port):
    srv, loop = self.init(host, port)
    print()
    if self.name:
        print('* Serving App {}'.format(self.name))
    print('* Serving On http://{host}:{port}'.format(host=host, port=port))
    print('* Press <CTRL-C> To Quit')
    workers = []
    try:
        for i in range(mp.cpu_count()-1):
            p = mp.Process(target=loop.run_forever)
            workers.append(p)
            p.start()
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        for p in workers:
            p.terminate()
        srv.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
        loop.close()
        pass
```

By the way, the `self.init` function works.

Answer (score 12):

I think, possibly, you're getting a little mixed up between parallel and concurrent programming. At first glance these may appear similar, but you'll quickly realise they are very different.

Asyncio helps with *concurrency*, all that means is that you can write your code in a non-blocking fashion. In other words, for I/O operations that take time to respond, such as network calls or disk access, you can have a particular piece of code *not block* your process as it waits for a response. This frees up CPU cycles for other async parts of your code in the *same thread*.

*Parallel* programming involves delegating small parts of some higher level task to multiple processes or threads and (usually) collecting and merging the results once they are all done.

Here's three scenarios to help differentiate:

You could write a server program such that every request received is handled by a new thread. That thread may be 100% blocking, so if it makes a network call, or reads a file from disk, it will wait until the I/O task has completed. But this is ok, because it's within it's own thread and the operating system will take care of switching which threads run when, on what cores, etc., so other threads will get a chance to run while that one is waiting for I/O. The downside to this is that there are resource overheads to threads, and the OS doesn't have perfect knowledge of what's happening within the threads, it's just doing it's best to make sure they all get a fair turn.

Another version of the server could be written in a concurrent fashion. Here only one thread is used, but the thread has detailed knowledge about what is blocking and what is executing (asyncio to the rescue), so you can write code that only handles one request at a time, but while a given request is waiting for data it lets another request do some processing, switching between tasks while others are blocked, all within the same thread/process. This is a much more efficient use of resources, but it generally only suits high I/O workloads, such as a simple server that reads/writes to a DB. It wouldn't be great for a server that has to do lots of big computations for each request as there wouldn't be I/O events mid-computation to trigger task switching.

A third scenario is where you combine these two concepts. This is useful to help scale an async server that handles a lot of I/O operations. It could also be used for one that needs to handle lots of connections and long running tasks, where tasks are delegated to threads, or other more complex configurations, but realistically it's most useful for scaling.

Asyncio has some [built in support for subprocesses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio-subprocess).

I highly recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/asyncio-threading-and-multiprocessing-in-python-4f5ff6ca75e8), it's very good.

Comment: I am talking about a asynchronous HTTP server that can use all of the cpu cores.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest trying to roll your own here. There are standard tools to do this. See [Gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#asyncio-workers) and this [example stack](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/secure-web-services-nginx-gunicorn-flask-myron-walker/)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. Gunicorn works on unix systems but not on windows.

Comment: You can use async web frameworks like https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/

Answer (score 1):

You can totally these days work with python 3.9+ and have these https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads

I have at the momment 3.8 but that `.to_thread` looks perfect to take advantage of the OS-threads on specific cases or create custom proxies in your code for the case of networking (like http server).

You can also work on "windows" over gunicorn using the wsl2 support of windows 10+ (there is an specific build 19041+ but you can just update your existing windows 10 to get there if you are under 19041) which is basically a running kernel on your windows at the same time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install ..  a matter of updates, running a command on powershell and installing ubuntu from start menu and type "ubuntu" like searching for something and off course clicking and installing it by accepting stuff on the microsoft store windows that pops-up.

Sooo sweet linux hybrid actually not only gunicorn but docker, ssh, console editors, search with "grep -rne" etc, attached you can look to my wsl2 instance (orange-black console) where all the linux happens.

I think my wsl2 instance shows up on windows as an extra/"private" network interface (IP "172.25.208.1") however i'm still confusing a bit on this one, what i know at this moment is that i can access the openssh server of my wsl2 instance (previous `apt install openssh-server` off course) through actually the localhost 127.0.0.1:22 (this is totally verificable when i stop the service)

From that point and i share you this command to redirect ports `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=2222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=22 connectaddress=127.0.0.1` (like socat but for native windows) so that way i can listen on all my windows interfaces (0.0.0.0) on port 2222, and point to this specific localhost (127.0.0.1) on port :22 where ssh server is, ta-da i can access ssh server of my wsl2 but from any device in my wifi LAN (my phone or just the wifi interface IP 192.168.1.5) that can get to my windows PC on port 2222 and that's great because it proves you can listen and run stuff on linux while having your windows as usual.

[image]

NOTE: i disabled my firewall as a fast one or you can just open the 2222 port of your windows firewall (This way i can access both computers i have in home "office laptop" and "room desktop" from the same lan using WinSCP).

NOTE: the "C:/" drive of windows is mounted on "/mnt/c/" of the wsl2/ubuntu instance, give it a try